# How to brand & sign the msi inside of a msp file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created a patch file (.msp) using the following wix guide
https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/patching/patch_building/

It generates a patch that works, however the MSI inside of the patch doesnt have any branding and displays default icons. It is also not signed.

Is there someway of defining the branding for the msp file?

Also when I created my original .exe file I had to extract the MSI out of it to be able to sign it. Is it the same process for the .msp files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I faced here was that the initial MSI's that I used to create the patch were not branded. So I was getting the default icons \ backgrounds when running the installation. This was because we were handling the branding in the .exe bundle. Once I created a bundle for the patch I could use the same branding. I could also extract the .exe engine and sign in which solved the other issue